# Pro JavaFX 2.0 "cowbell" example

Tags: java, javafx

In the "cowbell" example of Pro JavaFX 2.0 book, the single selection model is declared as follows:

```
public SingleSelectionModel genreSelectionModel;
```

Then later on the instance is used without constructor.

```
public void addListenerToGenreSelectionModel {
    genreSelectionModel.selectedIndexProperty().addListener(...); };
```

My question is Where is the `new` for `SingleSelectionModel` ?  As I see it, the variable is merely declared but the object is not created, like the IntegerProperties earlier in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the `genreSelectionModel` variable initialiazed by another function call?

Like :

```
    genreSelectionModel = listView.getSelectionModel()
```

**Edit :**
After a quick look to the example avaiable online at [google books](http://books.google.fr/books?id=Wp9Xrm1ujncC&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=cowbell%20example%20javafx&source=bl&ots=O-ykY4ohSG&sig=Jr9C1H7Qha2ExCMgddVzBrQgi_E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SBT2UfGPJYKQhQfBt4AQ&ved=0CEYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=genreSelectionModel&f=false) (pages 26-29) it seems that what you are refering to is the declaration of a field in a class. This has not to be initialized inside the class. You can see it as a class atribute and you can give it a value later in your program once you declared an Object of you custom type (containing your uninitialized variable)

Now, don't get me wrong, if you try to access this attribute without an initialization it will return a null pointer exception. But as it is done in the book you can create an Object and then initialize the variable with the value returned by another function.

```
    AudioConfigModel acModel = new AudioConfigModel();

    acModel.genreSelectionModel = genreChoiceBox.getSelectionModel();
    acModel.genreSelectionModel.selectFirst();
```

At the first line the genreSelectionModel attribute is null.
At the Second line there's a blank line for visibility
At the third you put into your attribute a "reference" to the genreChoiceBox own selectionModel.
Then at the fourth you call a function on your freshly instantiatedattribute

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the assignment in the main file.